# Prove orthogonal projections for a matrix A and its transpose

Tags: linear-algebra, orthogonal-matrices, projection-matrices

I'm trying to prove that a projection is orthogonal using:
$A ∈ \mathbb R^{m\times n} $ where $A^TA = I_n$, and I want to prove that $P=AA^T$ is an orthogonal projection.

I understand that an instance where $A^TA = I_n$ implies orthogonality, but what is the proof here?

Comment: Your asking a matrix $A \times A^T$, meaning an $m\times n$ matrix followed, multiplicatively,  by an $n \times m$ matrix, yielding an m x m matrix, results in $I^n$. Never, unless m = n.

Comment: You can start by showing it's a "regular" projection (i.e. show $P^2 = P$ this should be easy). Then show it is an orthogonal projection by showing that $\langle Px, y \rangle = \langle x, Py \rangle$, this should also be easy

Comment: Alternatively, think if you can actually figure out what $AA^T$ is, then the answer is pretty clear.

Comment: @amWhy you seem to have misread

Comment: A real matrix $M$ is an ortohogonal projection matrix iff $M^2=M$ and $M^T=M.$ There must be some "duplicate" proving this but I haven't been able to find it.